# Procurar data frames por nomes no R

Tags: r

Bom dia, eu gostaria de criar uma função a qual eu conseguisse utilizar um data frame com um nome que esteja salvo em um objeto. Exemplo:
Tenho os dataframes: df1, df2, df3
Todos com as colunas: x, y e z

```
df1
x y z
1 3 4
2 2 5
3 1 6

df2
x y z
1 3 4
2 2 5
3 1 6

df3
x y z
1 3 4
2 2 5
3 1 6
```

E nisso eu teria os objetos n1, n2 e n3 que teriam apenas os nomes dos objetos df1, df2 e df3

```
n1="df1"
n2="df2"
n3="df3"
```

E o que eu precisaria era pegar os objetos n's com os nomes dos dataframes e fazer com que eles recebam os dataframes com os respectivos nomes ou utilizar os n's como os próprios dataframes.

Isso seria possível?
Obrigado.

Comment: Veja a ajuda para a função `get`

Answer (score 0):

nesse caso você pode incluir esses data frames em uma lista e nomeá-la com o nome que quiser, cada índice da lista será um data frame.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1:3), y = c(3:1), z = c(4:6))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1:3), y = c(3:1), z = c(4:6))
df3 <- data.frame(x = c(1:3), y = c(3:1), z = c(4:6))

listaDataFrame <- list(df1,df2, df3)
names(listaDataFrame) = c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')
listaDataFrame['df1']

$df1
  x y z
1 1 3 4
2 2 2 5
3 3 1 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs <- paste0("df", sprintf("%02d", 1:10))

## Você pode atribuir valores de objetos diretamente às strings
## de nomes que quiser com a função assign()
for(i in dfs){
  my_dfi <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), size = 5),]
  assign(i, my_dfi)
}

## Você pode acessar os objetos chamando pelas strings de nomes
## com a função get() a alguma forma de loop
lista_dfs <- c()
for(i in dfs){
  lista_dfs[[i]] <- get(i)
}
```